# Javascript verify user input

Tags: javascript, input, verify

I need major help, I've been on this code for two days now. I have this table produced by javascript, which is used to confirm user input. If the user sees an error, they can click on the cell and it enables the user to edit the content right there.  I'm trying to setup where it displays if the users email is valid, or invalid. The script works good, but if the user deletes the full email, the content is no longer editable, which would not be good. My code so far is:

HTML:

```
<table id = 'confirm'>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <td id = 'tdEmail'>
      <div onkeyup = 'verifyEmail(this.parentNode.id)' contentEditable>
        abc@123.com
        <div id = 'validInvalid'>
          <span class = 'dgreen'> //Use to create a sort of green for valid email, when the user first sees the confirm table, the email is valid.
            <br/>Valid email!
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function verifyEmail(id){
  var email = document.getElementById.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
  var emailFilter = /^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/;
  if(!emailFilter.test(email)){
    document.getElementById("validInvalid").innerHTML = "<span class = 'red'><br/>Not a valid email!</span>";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("validInvalid").innerHTML = "<span class = 'dgreen'><br/>Valid email!</span>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Content isn't editable in a `div`. How are you making this editable in the first place? Why aren't you using `inputs`? You should look into verifying user input when an element loses focus on when the form is submitted (I assume there's more to all of this).

Comment: With the `contentEditable` attribute, @matthewpavkov?

Comment: fwiw document.getElementById is a function

Comment: fwiw im glad im using jquery

Comment: That regular expression is incorrect, and will disallow some valid addresses. In particular, double-quotes allow for spaces and other characters in the "local part" of an address.

Comment: Not really a qualified answer, but [do not validate email adresses](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) and use [mailcheck](https://github.com/Kicksend/mailcheck).

Comment: @matthewpavkov You can allow any content within a div to be editable. That was brought to my attention a few days ago.

Comment: @Pointy That regular expression works on any valid email I've tried it on. I got it from another site, can't remember which one (since I despise regular expressions). What regular expression would you recommend to be used instead?

Comment: Verifying RFC822 email addresses with a regular expression is hard, because the syntax is very complicated. There are businesses for example that give email addresses like `"John Smith"@business.com`. Personally I just try to make sure there's an `@something.something` suffix, and a non-empty local part, and leave it at that.

Comment: Really? I've never seen an email with quotes. Or spaces. that's odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div width gets reduced that is why you are not able to edit the content if the content is set to `''` one way to solve your problem is to give a fixed width to your div.

You can see the fix below : 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jR4pX/1/)

Comment: Or use `min-width` style attribute.

Comment: I'm getting `verifyEmail is not defined` in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: It works fine it my chrome I don't have firefox on this particular  computer, but I'm pretty sure they're just about the same. I fixed it using a fixed-width property.

Comment: @Vince I am glad it fixed your problem, please mark it as the solution if your problem is solved.

Comment: if you are using html5 an easier way to do it is to use `<input type="email" />`

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html